# How do I remove an invitation request notification?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm using FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', ... }) to invite a user but when the user accepts and logs into the app, the app icon still has a little red 1 on it.  How do I remove this notification or even get a list of notifications?  I've tried querying the graph explorer with manage_notifications permissions but I always end up with an empty data array.

I'd like to do as much as possible using the graph API and php if that's an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered thoroughily in the [requests documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). You would just need to issue a HTTP DELETE command to https://graph.facebook.com/requestID?access_token=...  The id's come as part of the querystring when the user clicks on the notification: `https://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]`

Comment: That makes sense but how do I query for requestIDs?

Comment: hmm, it seems that the request_ids param only appears from certain points of entry.  Is it possible to query for all request_ids for a particular user?

Comment: Yes just call /me/apprequests: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fapprequests

Comment: I think therein lies my confusion.  Like I stated in my original question, I tried that query (with all user and extended permissions) and I end up with an empty data array.

Comment: Note that the FQL you mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620714/get-request-ids-per-app does return data.  Is this a bug in the graph api?

Comment: If FQL is returning data and /me/apprequests isnt then yes it does sound like a bug and you should log it with Facebook.