# Get Request id's per app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-fql

From documentation:

> If a user clicks 'Accept' on a request, they will be sent to the canvas URL of the application that sent the request. This URL will contain an additional parameter, request_ids, which is a comma delimited list of Request IDs that a user is trying to act upon:
>   **http://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]**

How to get all request id's for the current app without knowing their id's and getting them from url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a FQL query:

```
SELECT recipient_uid, request_id, app_id 
FROM apprequest 
WHERE recipient_uid = me() AND app_id = 182197005148613
```

Comment: great answer ... but have you mentioned that it returns only 1 request in the array (latest one) ... facebook bug I guess

Comment: it should return more if there are more.